# Visual Studio 2008 Express and jQuery

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008

A very basic question.

I have just installed Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition and was was going to make some use of jQuery.

I heard that jQuery is now supported by Visual Studio, but my question is.

What do I need to do to use it? Is is already included in the VS installation or do I need to download it separately and reference the downloaded library?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the Visual Studio version of jQuery (should have vsdoc in the name) [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Download_jQuery).

You can use [this hotfix](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1736) to have the vsdoc js files be automatically detected, or use this slightly hackish workaround:

For jQuery intellisense in an ASP.NET file:

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% if (false) { %}
  <script src="jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% } %>
```

The "if (false)" bit ensures that the script won't ever actually be included, but intellisense will still pick up the reference.

For jQuery intellisense in another js file:

```
// <reference path="jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js" />
```

Comment: Thanks palmsey. It looks that the hotfix is not needed anymore (probably already included). After downloading the jQuery I simply referenced it like <script src="javascript/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and the Intellisense works fine. see also http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/10/28/rich-intellisense-for-jquery.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/07/hotfix-to-enable-vsdoc-js-intellisense-doc-files-is-now-available.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx) is the place to go to find the answer to this question (and most other current Visual Studio questions for that matter)

Comment: Thanks for the link but I have seen that post already. I was wondering if anything has changed since especially that now the Web Platform Installer is available

Answer (score 0):

It is not included. You just add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // You may specify partial version numbers, such as "1" or "1.3",
    //  with the same result. Doing so will automatically load the 
    //  latest version matching that partial revision pattern 
    //  (i.e. both 1 and 1.3 would load 1.3.2 today).
    google.load("jquery", "1.2.6");

    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
        // Place init code here instead of $(document).ready()
    });
</script>
```

to your master page or individual pages if not using a master page.

Comment: I think he's wanting the vsdoc version to get jQuery intellisense

Comment: @palmsay - yes you are right. I believe the approach suggested by dr is great for deployed code, but I believe I would need my local copy for Intellisense and for working without Internet access

Comment: There's a bit more to it than that...http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/